# Jenkins Grouping

Tags: jenkins, anthill

We're planning a migration from AnthillPro to another build system.
As of right now, we're checking the option of migrating to Jenkins.
We have a lot of different Products, and each Product has it's own repository and it's own builds for every branch.

In AnthillPro, There are several layers:
Folders -> Projects -> Worfklows -> Jobs -> Steps

In Jenkins I so far only came across:
Views -> Jobs -> Steps

Is there a way to group the Views?
Or are there any methods to group the different components?

How would you implement the structure of:
Product -> Branch -> Builds

If each product have several branches, and on in each branch you need to run several type of jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you need to install some plugins to achieve this.

I would recommend the [Team Views Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Views+Plugin) - it allows you to group jobs together and we use it heavily.  There is also a [Categories Jobs View](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Categorized+Jobs+View) plugin which I have not used but looks like it could provide a second level of grouping if needed.

Comment: The folders plugin is also a standard "recommended" plugin. That allows you to group your jobs and views into folders, and provide permissions, credentials, etc. on that folder.  Cloudbees offers even more control from this respect with Folders Plus and Role Bases Access control.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a "Folders" plugin that allows you to create jobs inside folders or folders inside folders:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin